# iOS UIButton with arabic title and image issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, uibutton

**Problem:**
When I set arabic string to UIButton and there is image, I got this
[image: UIButton with arabic localization]

But with other strings it is ok.

[image: UIButton with en localization]

**Details:**
What I set in
[image: Attributes inspector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the attribute inspector there is option available `Semantic`. you can set it in desired way.

[image]

You can set offset to button contents(image and title both), to image only and title only from `Size Inspector`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I found that there was image insets, that has constant value.

Comment: Kudos, glad to help you.